# How to tell if Chef client is installed on Linux?

Tags: linux, process, chef-infra, knife

I need a programmatic way (any way) to tell if Chef client is installed on Linux. The only way I can think of is to see if `/etc/chef` exists, but this might not be fool-proof. I was also thinking about checking to see the output of a `knife` command, but my *understanding* of Chef client is that `knife` is not an obligatory part of the client installation. In other words, I *believe* it's possible for the client to be installed, but not `knife`. Thoughts?

Comment: just look for it in your PATH

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `which knife` or `which chef-client` to determine (exist status `0`: command found, otherwise `1`).

While `knife` is used on the workstation, it should come with every installation of chef. But to be save, check for `chef-client`.